# Validating more that one email field

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using [Joren Rapini's validation code](http://jorenrapini.com/blog/javascript/the-simple-quick-and-small-jquery-html-form-validation-solution) to for my online form. [Joren's Website](http://jorenrapini.com/blog/javascript/the-simple-quick-and-small-jquery-html-form-validation-solution)

It allows you to check to see if an email address has been correctly entered, but I have 2 email addresses that I want to validate in the form.

Any idea how I would do this?

I've tried adding in email = $("#youremail"); as well as the one that's currently in the code which is email = $("#receiveremail"); but it only works for one.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Place ID's of all required fields here.
    required = ["youremail", "name", "receiveremail", "message"];

    // If using an ID other than #email or #error then replace it here
    email = $("#receiveremail");
    errornotice = $("#error");

    // The text to show up within a field when it is incorrect
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field";
    emailerror = "Not a vaild email";
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run the validation code for your other field

in document.ready

```
otheremail = $("#otheremail");
```

in form submit

```
if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(otheremail .val())) {
            otheremail .addClass("needsfilled");
            otheremail .val(emailerror);
        }
```

No offense to Joren Rapini but this code is hacky and shouldn't be used for other than the smallest purpose.

Answer (score 1):

He doesn't do a great job of explaining this, but it's fairly straightforward.  You have to validate two separate email fields:

```
if (!/^S+@S+.S+$/.test(email.val())) {
    email.addClass("needsfilled");
    email.val(emailerror);
}
var email2 = $("#youremail");
if (!/^S+@S+.S+$/.test(email2.val()) {
```

Of course it would be better to loop over the emails in a similar setup to how `required` is done.

Use `var` too.